# cocoa error 134100 again again (The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, cocoa, core-data

I created a Core Data model in xcode 6.0.1, then I began to test the framework possibilities by creating a simple entity with three fetch requests.
I used the xcode tool.

(sorry can't post image)

```
RequestTask{
String argnames
String argvalues
Integer16 type
String method
}
```

I did some basic tests: create, fetch, update, and delete. Everything was working fine until I got that famous error message:

EDIT : **this bug happens even the first time the store is created, so how could the model use to create the store different from the one used to open it a few lines later?**

```
Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x7a6e0a80 {metadata={
NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
    RequestTask = <835609ac 6e164427 c573e9d7 c56ba74e b1cc0283 75a99bb9 0e74286d c95ce429>;
};
NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
    ""
);
NSStoreType = SQLite;
NSStoreUUID = "7D5176D6-DBFE-41B3-825C-BEE1F8E74B3E";
"_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
}, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
metadata =     {
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 519;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
        RequestTask = <835609ac 6e164427 c573e9d7 c56ba74e b1cc0283 75a99bb9 0e74286d c95ce429>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "7D5176D6-DBFE-41B3-825C-BEE1F8E74B3E";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;
};
reason = "The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store";
```

}

I just used the template code pot the core data app with some sample on AppleDev.

```
#pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"AppBesson" withExtension:@"momd"];
    //NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"TestModel" withExtension:@"momd"];

    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"appbesson.sql"];
    //NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"testmodel.sql"];

    NSError *error = nil;
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES};

    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:@"Default" URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error]) {
        /*
         ...

         */
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Here is the funny part : I have really searched here, on google, on AppleDevelopper... I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

- [xcode-4-3-unable-to-load-persistent-store-userdictionary-sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040681/xcode-4-3-unable-to-load-persistent-store-userdictionary-sqlite)
- [the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881453/the-model-used-to-open-the-store-is-incompatible-with-the-one-used-to-create-the)
- [cant-find-model-for-source-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950063/cant-find-model-for-source-store)
- [cocoa-error-134100-again-model-used-to-open-is-incompatible-from-model-used-t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923955/cocoa-error-134100-again-model-used-to-open-is-incompatible-from-model-used-t)
- [incompatible-object-model-version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790933/incompatible-object-model-version)
- [how-to-create-the-magic-xcdatamodeld-folder-package/4518137#4518137](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518000/how-to-create-the-magic-xcdatamodeld-folder-package/4518137#4518137)

SO I already try to :

- **uninstall the app on the simulator + reset simulator + project clean and build**
- **delete manually the .sqlite .mom .momd in the document folder of the simulator's device**
- **create another model (empty) for test, it also fail so I have deleted everything about it**
- **tried on a real iPhone, same problem...**

Then here I came, I'm sorry if I miss something already said somewhere but I have tried every question directly related and A LOT of indirectly related...

Insults are fine if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by trials but I can't explain why...
Just set the configuration to **nil** instead of **@"Default"** when adding the store.

Comment: Why were you using default? Unless you've created a configuration with that name, it wouldn't exist.

Comment: The default configuration is named "Default", I just thought that instead of nil...